# What is the time zone used in the Google trends data?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-trends

I have not been able to find an answer in the docs, and since the lowest level of aggregation is daily I cannot figure it out from the data. If I use the Google trends API (or trends.google.com), what is the time zone for the underlying data used in the aggregation? Is it UTC, my local time zone, the time zone of the country where the search was conducted?

Answer (score 4):

The data is aggregated as full UTC days.
It used to be mentioned in the help center for Trends.

Comment: I tried to search in the Google Trends help but nothing: no item for "time zone" or "UTC".
I do some test changing location, all around the world, and yes, it seems to be "UTC".

Thanks

Comment: It is not mentioned explicitly, but aggregations for day/week/month/year use UTC for counting full days.

Answer (score 1):

cet in the netherlands. Sirach for breakfast in your language

Comment: I can't understand what you mean with your second sentence "Sirach for breakfast in your language". Please elaborate.